# Comunication tcp server c/ client java

Tags: java, c, server, tcp, client

i have some trouble with comunication between a c server and a java client.

***How i recive in c***

```
void *connection_handler(void* args){
    int sock = *(int*)args;
    char op_code [sizeof(uint8_t)];
    char len [sizeof(uint8_t)];

    while(true){
        if(read(sock,&op_code,(sizeof(uint8_t)))==0 || atoi(op_code)==0)
          {printf("Error reading op_code\n");break;}

        if(read(sock,&len,(sizeof(uint8_t)))==0 || atoi(len)==0)
          {printf("Error reading len\n");break;}

        printf("op code->%d\n",atoi(op_code));
        printf("len ->%d\n",atoi(len));
    }

    printf("Client is now disconnected\n");
    close(sock);
    free((int*)args);
    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

***How i connect to server and send data in java***

```
       private void connectToServer(){
        try {
            SocketAddress sockaddr =
                    new InetSocketAddress(MainActivity.SERVER_IP, MainActivity.SERVER_PORT);
            socket = new Socket();
            socket.connect(sockaddr, 3000);
            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: connesso");

        }
        catch (SocketTimeoutException te) {
            Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: non connesso, time out exeption" + te);
            sendDataToActivity(MainActivity.ERROR, MainActivity.TIME_OUT_EXEPTION);
            te.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: non connesso" + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Send message to server.
     * @param username
     * @param psw
     */
    public void sendSignIn (String username,String psw){
        new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                //Invio il command_code e la lunghezza del messaggio al server

                try {
                    dataOutputStream.writeBytes("1");
                   // dataOutputStream.close();
                    dataOutputStream.writeBytes("2");
                    //dataOutputStream.writeBytes(username);
dataOutputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
```

***Output of this code***

```
op_code -> 12 (Should be 1 but can't understand why my read read both)
len -> 2
```

Probably the problem it's caused by the size of op_code and len but honestly i can't understand how fix it.
Can some one illuminate me pls?

Comment: Your problem is with the DataOutputStream. This is Java-only. Just use plain Input/Output Streams

Comment: This is a C problem. Do you know how strings work in C?

Comment: @user253751 did u mean the &?

Comment: @Solan I mean what I said: Do you know how strings work in C?

Comment: @user253751 yes  but I still don't understand the problem...

Comment: In one sentence, tell me how strings work in C

Comment: Array of char... maybe i should add the end line char.